# Xcode defaults for signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

In a new Project created in Xcode 7 GM, the default values for the Project code-signing are:

```
PROJECT
  myProject
    Code Signing
      Code Signing Identity
        Debug               Don't Code Sign   //#
            Any iOS SDK     iPhone Developer  //##
        Release             Don't Code Sign
            Any iOS SDK     iPhone Developer // why not Distribution?
```

(Find this in Project > Build Settings > Code Signing)

1. How do lines marked # and ## differ? If any iOS SDK uses iPhone Developer, when will the Debug value apply? For any non-iOS SDK? How often would a non-iOS SDK show up in an iOS app?
2. Why is the last entry iPhone Developer? One would expect iPhone Distribution. That option does appear in the pop-up editor. Would it make sense to choose that identity instead?

Comment: Signing identity is overridden during the submission process (Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Upload to App Store...).

Comment: Also, please note that Xcode 7 Final got released on September 16th and has a different build number than Xcode 7 GM.

Answer (score 1):

When the app is uploaded to the store, default signing identity is overridden.

Comment: I believe the foregoing answers address question 2. Thanks. How about question 1?

Comment: But re question 2, the foregoing answers just raise more questions. Like: how does Xcode decide which identities to use when overriding? And if overriding happens, what is the point of the overridden settings?